# convert Log back to original value

Tags: python, numpy

this where i convert to one of my independent variable to  and the dependent variable to Nlog

```
mask = dtd['value_eur'] > 0  # Create a boolean mask for non-zero values
dtd['value_eur'] = np.log(dtk.loc[mask, 'value_eur'])  # Apply log only to non-zero values
mass = dtd['wage_eur'] > 0  # Create a boolean mask for non-zero values
dtd['wage_eur'] = np.log(dtk.loc[mask, 'wage_eur'])  # Apply log only to non-zero values
```

this is the X and y values  for prediction

```
X = dtd.drop(['value_eur' ], axis=1)
y = dtd['value_eur']
```

this is my model fitting

```
regressor =gs.best_estimator_

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
regs= regressor.predict(X_test)

mae3 = mean_absolute_error(y_test, regs)

print(f"Mean Absolute Error: {mae3}")
```

this where i printed my values

```
results1 = pd.DataFrame({ ' grids predicted values':(regs),  '  true values':y_test})

results1.head()
```

```
    grids predicted values  true values
60199   15.665110   15.761421
23743   12.557003   12.765688
58428   15.386219   15.424948
34538   15.588066   15.226498
108229  14.202580   14.457364
```

how to make the values above display the original values as it is in the original dataset

```
np.exp(y_test)
```

Comment: What values aren't matching?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the np.exp() function to reverse the logarithmic transformation.

```
regs= regressor.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.exp(regs)

mae3 = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

print(f"Mean Absolute Error: {mae3}")

results1 = pd.DataFrame({ ' grids predicted values':(y_pred),  '  true values':y_test})

results1.head()
```

Comment: Please I want to know if it is right to log only one of the independent variable because it has an excessively large value while leaving the other

Comment: @SamuelOsaghae please create a new question if you want an answer to another question, otherwise existing answers will be too clustered for other people to read and learn.